# Adding choice parameter in Jenkins that lists options given by a bash command

Tags: java, jenkins

When creating a project in Jenkins, I currently have a "Choice parameter" (a combobox) that lets the user pick one of several options. In general, I have to go and edit this project every time a new option comes to life or some option no longer makes sense. This can get troublesome. I was wondering if there was any way to have the contents of this combobox be calculated by running a bash command?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Did you try [Dynamic Parameter Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Dynamic+Parameter+Plug-in)? It might suites what you need.